# react-bootstrap-typeahead: Could not select the highlighted item from the dropdown using enter key

Tags: reactjs

I'm using AsyncTypeahead of bootstrap-typeahead to get suggestions from API call. Everything works well but I couldn't select the highlighted item from the dropdown using enter key. After highlight an item, when I press enter, nothing happens. I can only select the item using the mouse.
Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please post some code to show what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is to add a call back function to handle onKeyDown, select the current active item as this.container.querySelector('.dropdown-item.active');
and click the item if it exists.